# Lumify with Docker Installation

Tags: ubuntu, java, docker

I am trying to run lumify with docker as follows
1. go to the lumify directory path
2. docker/build-dev.sh

after the command this starts installing packges
 while calling installation/java.sh I am getting this following error

```
Step 11/79 : ADD scripts/install-java.sh /opt/lumify/scripts/install-java.sh
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a9707abe3359
Step 12/79 : ADD config/java/java.sh /etc/profile.d/java.sh
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 14b21e6b06f9
Step 13/79 : ENV PATH $PATH:/opt/jdk/bin
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 33b7524471db
Step 14/79 : ENV JAVA_HOME /opt/jdk
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ce6960fe7bb5
Step 15/79 : ENV _JAVA_OPTIONS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 6edff9896d94
Step 16/79 : RUN /bin/bash /opt/lumify/scripts/install-java.sh
 ---> Running in 3ac653d91653
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  5307  100  5307    0     0   2576      0  0:00:02  0:00:02 --:--:--  2576

gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
/opt/lumify/scripts/install-java.sh: line 29: cd: /opt/jdk: No such file or directory
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 3496k  100 3496k    0     0   328k      0  0:00:10  0:00:10 --:--:--  447k
Unpacking...
Checksumming...
0
0
This is not a proper JDK directory.  Exiting install.
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 1644k  100 1644k    0     0   353k      0  0:00:04  0:00:04 --:--:--  426k
Unpacking...
Checksumming...
0
0
This is not a proper JDK directory.  Exiting install.
The command '/bin/sh -c /bin/bash /opt/lumify/scripts/install-java.sh' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

**Note:** in original installation/java.sh script it was like below

```
# download the archive
if [ ! -f "$ARCHIVE_DIR/jdk-7u71-linux-x64.tar.gz" ]; then
    curl -L -o $ARCHIVE_DIR/jdk-7u71-linux-x64.tar.gz            https://bits.lumify.io/extra/jdk-7u71-linux-x64.tar.gz
fi
```

since **https://bits.lumify.io/ is not working(server is down)** I replace this URL with the  **http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u71-b14/jdk-7u71-linux-x64.tar.gz**

please can anyone tell me the solution to resolve this. All this error I am getting while I am trying to run **lumify demo** using docker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That download link for the archive redirects you to an error page if you haven't agreed to the OTN license terms. The curl call for your oracle link doesn't send the necessary cookie data to indicate that this requirement is fulfilled, so it is redirected to downloading the HTML error page which is of course "not in gzip format" when tar calls gzip to decompress it.

After looking at the script it looks like the necessary cookie name and value are in the commented out wget argument on line 3 (oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie) so try changing the curl line to

```
curl -L -o $ARCHIVE_DIR/jdk-7u71-linux-x64.tar.gz -b 'oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie' http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u71-b14/jdk-7u71-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

Of course you could instead just download the archive using your browser and save it as `/tmp/lumify/archives/jdk-7u71-linux-x64.tar.gz` before running the script. The script checks for the existence of this archive before attempting to use curl to download it so you shouldn't have a problem if you do it this way.

Comment: I did the same as u told like downloading archive  creating /tmp/lumify/archives/jdk-7u71-linux-x64.tar.gz manually , but stll i am getting same error

Comment: I tried with curl -L -o $ARCHIVE_DIR/jdk-7u71-linux-x64.tar.gz -b 'oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie' http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u71-b14/jdk-7u71-linux-x64.tar.gz also , but same error

Comment: Ok I just tried it. It seems that the curl edit I suggested works fine, but unfortunately many of the other steps rely on bits.lumify.io as well so those are the ones failing. So, you will ultimately have to find a mirror for every bits.lumify.io link in the install scripts, since it doesn't seem like that server is coming back anytime soon (lumify doesn't seem to be actively developed anymore).